# What is the best way to sum all numbers in a list of various runtime types in dart?

Tags: dart

Given a list of various types, what is the best way to sum all of the elements that are of type int or double.

For example, given this list

```
List list = [10, 4.5, "String"]
```

how can I write a function that will sum the numbers to return 14.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
void main() {
  List<Object> list = [10, 4.5, "String"];
  var sum = 0.0;
  
  for (final item in list) {
    if (item is num) {
      sum += item;
    }
  }
  
  print("Sum: $sum");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
void main() {
  final list = [10, 4.5, "String"];
  final sum = list.whereType<num>().reduce((a, b) => a + b);
  print(sum); // 14.5
}
```